# How can I strip the version from the output directory of maven-dependency-plugin:unpack?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I need to unpack an artifact, and I need to use it's unpacked location in several places (in multiple files).  I don't want to have to update all the copies of that location every time I change versions.  Is there a way I can strip the version from the output directory?  It doesn't look like stripVersion is supported with the unpack mojo.

Comment: Can you post your `maven-dependency-plugin` configuration from your `pom` so we can debug?

Answer (score 0):

Does the plugin you are using to create the artifact provide a `xyzName` property?  For example the `jar-plugin` provides the [`finalName`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#finalName) and the `war-plugin` has the [`warName`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warName).

If so you can set the property to some fixed value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<properties>
    <extracted-artifact-location>${project.build.directory}/extracted-artifact</extracted-artifact-location>
</properties>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId><fixme></groupId>
                                <artifactId><fixme></artifactId>
                                <version><fixme></version>
                                <outputDirectory>${extracted-artifact-location}</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This is what I have, and it puts the extracted artifact in "${extracted-artifact-location}/${artifactId}-${version}/".  I want it in "${extracted-artifact-location}/${artifactId}/"

Comment: @Jared With this configuration I end up with the contents of the dependency extracted directly in the `${extracted-artifact-location}` directory. You'll need to post your configuration for more help. Please show the relevant configuration for the `maven-dependency-plugin` from your pom and parent pom it inherits from.